# How to parse the result from jquery upload file plugin with jquery.iframe-transport plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, jquery-iframe-transport

I use jQuery File Upload Plugin 5.26
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Because I need to append extra parameters for my file.ashx to process request, I added jquery.iframe-transport.js as suggested in [jQuery File Uploader IE9 Not posting any params on Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699617/jquery-file-uploader-ie9-not-posting-any-params-on-upload)

My file.ashx still returns me json string (text/plain) result as shown in fiddler, but in the done callback I only got some weird data structure which contains the forms, files and html element kind of like a iframe or stuff. How can I get my json string (text/plain) result?

Thanks.

Comment: OK, problem solved by google

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/659#issuecomment-2999298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/659#issuecomment-2999298

the result is wrapped into HTML.

So the callback just needs one more step to extract the result from HTML like below

```
function(e, data) {
    var result = $.parseJSON($('pre', data.result).text());
    // and result can be used like before
}
```